# How to create a PHP function that contain a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, function

Hello at the moment I'm using a **PHP** file called *select_Type.php* that contain a MySQL query to create a **`<select></select>`** Box into HTML. I'm using `include_once` to link my *admin.php* and *./Includes/select_Type.php*. I already created a file called *./Includes/functions.php* where all my querys should be set in **PHP functions**.

I would like to learn more about functions.

**Admin page admin.php where the `<select></select>` is :**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once './Includes/functions.php';

CheckLogIn('Superadmin');
SelectType();
//require_once './Includes/select_Type.php';
require_once './Includes/register.php';
?>
```

**select_type.php :**

```
    <?php
require_once 'functions.php'; 

$querySQL = "SELECT * FROM tbltype";
$queryResult = GetQuery($querySQL);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult)){
    $dataArrayType[] = $row;
}
?>
```

**What I tried:**

```
<?php
function SelectType() {
    GLOBAL $_POST;
    $querySQL = "SELECT * FROM tblType";
    $queryResult=GetQuery($querySQL);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult)) {
        $dataArrayType[] = $row;
    }
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are calling the `SelectType();` function, but that function has no return value, and not print anything, so it do nothing, just collect tha data into an array, what array will be not accessable outside of the function.

Comment: Also, `$_POST` is already a global, you don't need the `global $_POST;` line..

Comment: Thanks both of you, but lolka_bolka I'm not really undertanding how to do it can explain it to me ?

Comment: When you run this function it doesn't know what to send back since you havent specified it. It will run the function but you never give a 'echo' or 'return' so you will see nothing. Take a look at [This!](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

Comment: I tried `return array ($dataArrayType);` but still not working

Comment: and what if you only `return $dataArrayType;`? Place it between the 2 `}` near the end.

Comment: Then you should be able to call it by using something like `$data = SelectType();` This way `$data` should be your entire array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all especially Déjà vu !!!!!
You were all very helpfull.

The problem was, how most of you told me: I didn't returned the value.

## Before:

```
<?php
function SelectType() {
    GLOBAL $_POST;
    $querySQL = "SELECT * FROM tblType";
    $queryResult=GetQuery($querySQL);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult)) {
        $dataArrayType[] = $row;
    }
}
?>
```

## Now:

I deleted the `GLOBAL $_POST` becauce `$_POST` is already `GLOBAL`.(Thanks to ɴ ᴀ ᴛ ʜ)

```
<?php
function SelectType() {
    $querySQL = "SELECT * FROM tblType";
    $queryResult=GetQuery($querySQL);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult)) {
        $dataArrayType[] = $row;
    }
    return $dataArrayType;
}
?>
```

### admin.php

I put my function `SelectType()`  in my `foreach`. Et voila!

```
    <select type="text" id="register_type" name="register_type" required>
        <?php
        foreach (SelectType() as $row) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['idType'] . "'>" . $row['dtType'] . '</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this:**

```
function sel($table,$field="*", $condition="1",$sort="" ){
    if($sort!='') $sort="order by $sort ";
    //echo "select $field  from $table where $condition $sort ";
    $sel_query=mysql_query("select $field  from $table where $condition $sort ");
    //$sel_result=array();
    while($temp_res=@mysql_fetch_array($sel_query))
    {
        $sel_result[]=$temp_res;
    }
    return isset($sel_result)?$sel_result: 0;
}
```

And get result:

```
$temp_res=sel("post","*"," userid ='".$frnd['friend']."' ORDER BY id DESC");
    if($temp_res)foreach($temp_res as $row){
        echo $row['content'];
    }
```

Comment: Using `@` is very bad practise. Please, don't promote bad practise. Edit: Additionally, you're using the `mysql_*` functions, which are deprecated and your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.